# Why do high altitude sky-divers say 'Exit' multiple times?

Tags: altitude, skydiving

This is something that has always puzzled me.
https://sndup.net/6vn8/a

Unfortunately, I can't find a video in which I heard them say it, but right before they left the plane, I heard

> Exit exit exit exit exit exit

through a radio or megaphone.
I found audio of this, but maybe you might not be able to benefit from it because there are no visual cues.

Comment: I can't find the video I saw three years ago, but I did get an audio version.

Comment: Just a guess, but exiting an aircraft in flight, being a terrifying (and thrilling) experience, might require some extra encouragement. As well as assurance that your weren't just saying "exit" casually in a sentence, but over the sound of rushing air and anticipation, you mistake it for an instruction.

Comment: I thought the proper term is [Geronimo](https://youtu.be/MlmQONDjwWM)